# Android SQLiteOpenHelper OFFSET

Tags: java, android, sql, sqliteopenhelper

I have SQLiteOpenHelper Database in my android app.
On PC where i have derby database, i use this sql order.

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String sqlOrder = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " ORDER BY ID ASC OFFSET 40 ROWS";
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery(sqlOrder, null);
```

But on android doesnt work.

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "OFFSET": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM Messages_table ORDER BY ID ASC OFFSET 40 ROWS
```

Any substitute?

Comment: How can you access the database on your PC from android device ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have syntax for SQL Server and not for SQL used in sqlite.

Instead of `OFFSET 40 ROWS`, use something like `LIMIT x OFFSET y` where `x` is the number of rows you want to retrieve at a time and `y` is your offset you want to start retrieving results from.